# Custom flow - delegation

Tags: openiddict

I was wondering if it is possible to implement with `openiddict` a delegation grant type similar to the one implemented [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) with `Identity Server`.

```
var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken);
if (result.IsError)
{
    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
    return;
}
```

Is there any equivalent method to `ValidateAccessTokenAsync` in `openiddict` in order to validate the token and access some of its properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of standard token exchange is tracked by https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1249.

In the meantime, you can override the default `ValidateTokenParameter` handler to work with your custom grant and extract the access token from the customer parameter you use:

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/422d8979adb8cdebc6c8c8e14faa1d736208271e/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerHandlers.cs#L168

Then, you can call the `IOpenIddictServerDispatcher.DispatchAsync()` method with an instance of `ProcessAuthenticationContext` to trigger an authentication event. If `IsRejected` is `true`, this means the token is not valid. Otherwise, you'll be able to access its claims principal.

Comment: Thank you Kévin!